# How can I prevent Hibernate from updating NULL values

Tags: hibernate, null, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

Is there a setting in hibernate to **ignore null values** of properties when saving a hibernate object?

**NOTE** 
In my case I am de-serializing JSON to a Hibernate Pojo via Jackson.

The JSON only contains some of the fields of the Pojo. If I save the Pojo the fields that were not in the JSON are null in the Pojo and hibernate UPDATES them.

I came accross the setting `updateable=false`, but this isn't a 100% solution.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property

Maybe somebody has another idea...

**NOTE 2:**

According to the Hibernate Docs the `dynamicUpdate` **annotation** does exactly that

> dynamicInsert / dynamicUpdate (defaults to false): 
>   specifies that INSERT / UPDATE SQL should be generated at runtime
>   and contain only the columns **whose values are not null**.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-class

Funny enough if you define it in XML via `dynamic-update` the docu do not mention the hanlding of NULL values.

> dynamic-update (optional - defaults to false):
>  specifies that UPDATE SQL should be > generated at runtime and can contain only those columns whose values have changed.

Due to the fact that I'm using both annotations **AND** xml configuration, hibernate seems to ignores my `dynamicUpdate=true` annotation.

Comment: you can use dynamic-update to avoid properties coming in SQL which haven't been updated but it is generally advised to use this setting only when the entity has too properties (columns > 50) [reference : Java Persistence with Hibernate 2006 edition]. @hvgotcodes is right in pointing out that you dont have to map fields if they are never going to be persisted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should first load the object using the primary key from DB and then copy or deserialize the JSON on top of it.

There is no way for hibernate to figure out whether a property with value null has been explicitly set to that value or it was excluded.

If it is an insert then dynamic-insert=true should work.

Comment: lead me to the right direction. Best is to load the existing object and update this object accordingly. Jackson even has a default behavior for that http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureUpdateValue

Comment: I don't have any null value in my db. So nobody will never set to null anything explicitly. Is there any other solution for me? @gkamal

Comment: Issuing `SELECT` before `UPDATE` is an additional load on DB and a decline in response time SLA. It is ridiculous that the framework has such limited ways to address that.

Answer (score 0):

I have googled a lot about this,but there is no the very solution for me.So,I used a not graceful solution to cover it.

```
  public void setAccount(Account a) throws HibernateException {
    try {
        Account tmp = (Account) session.
                get(Account.class, a.getAccountId());
        tmp.setEmail(getNotNull(a.getEmail(), tmp.getEmail()));            
        ...
        tmp.setVersion(getNotNull(a.getVersion(), tmp.getVersion()));
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(tmp);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        logger.error(e.toString());
        throw e;
    }
}

public static <T> T getNotNull(T a, T b) {
    return b != null && a != null && !a.equals(b) ? a : b;
}
```

I receive an `Object a` which contains a lot of fields.Those field maybe `null`,but   I don't want to update them into mysql.
I get an `tmp Obejct` from db, and change the field by method `getNotNull`，then update the Object.

[a Chinese description edition](https://github.com/Acceml/Coolcode/blob/master/dal-hibernate-UpdateNotnullField.md)

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this problem and I did a work-around to help myself through this. May be a little ugly but may work just fine for you too. Kindly if someone feels there's an adjustment that's good to have feel free to add. Note that the work-around is meant for valid entity classes and whose some fields include nullable attributes. Advantage with this one is it reduces the number of queries.

```
public String getUpdateJPQL(Object obj, String column, Object value) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {

//obj -> your entity class object
//column -> field name in the query clause
//value -> value of the field in the query clause

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
    Map format = new HashMap();
    if (value instanceof String) {
        value = "'" + value + "'";
    }

    map.keySet()
            .forEach((str) -> {
                Object val = map.get(str);
                if (val != null) {
                    format.put("t.".concat(str), "'" + val + "'");
                }
            });
    String formatStr = format.toString();
    formatStr = formatStr.substring(1, formatStr.length() - 1);

    return "update " + obj.getClass()
            .getSimpleName() + " t set " + formatStr + " where " + column + " = " + value + "";

}
```

Example: For entity type `User` with fields: `userId`, `userName` & `userAge`; the result query of `getUpdateJPQL(user, userId, 2)` should be `update User t set t.userName = 'value1', t.userAge = 'value2' where t.userId = 2`
Note that you can use json annotations like `@JsonIgnore` on `userId` field to exclude it in deserialization i.e. in the generated query.
You can then run your query using entityManager or hibernate sessions.