# Ignore null values of entity bean while updating the table using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

[Stuck on the same problem](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=977537) Is there any method to ignore `null` values when updating the database in `Hibernate`?

Whenever you call update(); of Session, it will also update the null values found in the object.

Example:

```
User user = new User();
user.setUserId(5);
user.setUserName("Maarten");
user.setUserFirstName(null); // but in database this value is not null

session.update( user);
```

OR

```
session.saveOrUpdate( user);
```

The DB will now update the user, but will set the user firstname to null (because it is null in the object).

Is there any way or method in Hibernate to avoid this (I don't want to fire a select/ update query to set the bean)? that it will ignore the null value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent Hibernate from updating NULL values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517546/how-can-i-prevent-hibernate-from-updating-null-values)

Comment: so you want to set FirstName value as the value it is there in the DB previously.You dont  want to update that FirstName Right ?

Comment: @Ganesh yup you are right.

Answer (score 2):

[hibernate-dynamic-update](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/)

> The dynamic-update attribute tells Hibernate whether to include unmodified properties in the SQL UPDATE statement.

Comment: dynamic-update is depreciated use instead @DynamicUpdate annotation https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-dynamicupdate

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the abstraction level you wish to control, and the business rules of the object:

- Is the field *really* nullable, or are you simply using it as a DTO? perhaps you need an intermediate object to control null values
- What happens with new users (as in the example)? I should ignore the null value, then which value should be persisted, the default one?

If, anyway, you define your requisites in a lower level, e.g. "do not include null values in update queries", you can use the following:

- sql-update annotation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html). You can use a custom sql query or procedure to control values
- dynamicUpdate is about changes, not values, so I think it's not really suitable
- Use a [EntityListener](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html), and an auxiliary transient field to revert changes if desired.
- Other options: use an [interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/events.html) or even create a [custom dialect](https://community.jboss.org/thread/195653?tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is, `load` the bean using `get(object)` method from the session and then set/change the values. But this comes with an overhead of one ***extra*** call to the database. *Or you can create a custom query if making an extra call is crucial.*

Edit: if `bean` is cached then `get(object)` will not be a performance hit.

Comment: Other then overhead, in case that the field is being updated from another process you might end up overriding the value (read-write race-cond). Transaction is one possible solution but I prefer to split into 2 tables or update the specific fields carefully.